# Investigate of convergence $\int_0^1 \frac1{\sqrt {1-x^3}} dx$

Tags: real-analysis

> Investigate of convergence $\int_0^1 \frac1{\sqrt {1-x^3}} dx$

I tried to use asymptotic convergence  criterion however for all function $g$ and $f$ I got $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\rightarrow 0$ so I couldn't use it. That is why I think that it is not convergent but I can't prove it.
 Can you help me?

Comment: According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt(1-x%5E3)+from+0+to+1), your function does converge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:
$$\int_0^1 \frac1{\sqrt {1-x^3}} dx<\int_0^1 \frac1{\sqrt {1-x^2}} dx$$

Comment: And use  $x= \sin t$, yes?

Comment: $(\sin^{-1}x)'=\frac1{\sqrt {1-x^2}}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^3}}dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}\sqrt{1+x+x^2}} dx$$
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x+x^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \neq 0,\infty$$
so $$ \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^3}}dx \text{ is convergent} \qquad \Leftrightarrow \qquad\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}} dx\text{ is convergent} $$